# How to set project environment on Ubuntu to interact with soap web services?

Tags: ubuntu, soap, dart, monodevelop, development-environment

I need to use ubuntu (my dart server is there) to call soap web services wsdl and convert to data to json. For this I was planing to use monodevelop on ubuntu 18.04.

My main aim is to allow my flutter app to send data to dart server and from dart server use socket programming to connect monodevelop project with data, and from monodevelop project consume remote soap web services wsdl. 
In return get data from soap web services wsdl to dart server convert data to json and send it to flutter app.

my main problem I don't know how to setup the programming environment on ubuntu.

My question is; How to set project environment on Ubuntu to interact with soap web services?

Comment: Add a Web Reference?

Comment: browser context menu: Add / Add Web Reference.